# plot confusion matrix for semantic segmentation ResNet model in fastai

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, confusion-matrix, fast-ai, semantic-segmentation

I am using fatai v2 for classifying lands using satellite imageries, and I am struggling with plotting confusion matrix for my test dataset using fastai.

This is the code I used:

```
learn = unet_learner(dls,resnet34, metrics=accuracy, self_attention=True, act_cls=Mish)
lr=5.248074739938602e-05
learn.fit_flat_cos(1000, slice(lr))
interp = SegmentationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)
losses,idxs = interp.top_losses()
top_losses, top_idxs = interp.top_losses()
```

but when I run this line for plotting confusion matrix:

```
mean_cm, single_img_cm = interp._generate_confusion()
```

it shows an error that interp doesn't have _generate_confusion().

AttributeError: 'SegmentationInterpretation' object has no attribute '_generate_confusion'

I upgraded fastai to the latest version, but it is not working.
Can anybody help me to find a code for plotting the confusion matrix for image segmentation models?